# Redirect All Browsers and Devices Besides Android For A Single Page

Tags: javascript, android, .htaccess, redirect

What I need to do is redirect all devices besides android, including desktops. To a different page.

What I had in place was

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width >= 800) {
document.location = "https://website.com/normalpage/";
}
//-->
</script>
```

But that is a screen size redirect and it was allowing android tablets to view the wrong page which has issues on android.

What I am trying to do: I have traffic click on a link in my site, if it is an android device they stay on the page, if it is not an android device they goto the normal non android bugged page.

It maybe easier to reverse the redirect so everyone goes to bugged page, then if android is detected they get sent to the non bugged page, but for terms of a fail safe, I prefer everyone load the non bug, so if the script fails or breaks they will still load the non bugged page correctly.

As always, I appreciate your help fellow stackers.

Well with the question being closed for being identical to a non identical question. Idk if this can even be indexed but here is the answer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {

} else {
window.location = 'https://redirect.com/redirect123/';
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I looked at your suggested duplicate question, I see how it is relevant but I don't see how to take a user agent specifically and redirect them for a single page.

Comment: I figured it out, this is exactly what I was looking for 
     <script type="text/javascript">
     <!--
     var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
     var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
     if(isAndroid) {
 
     } else {
     window.location = 'https://redirect.com/redirect';
     }
    //-->
    </script>